# Implementing a hash function in Python

Tags: python, arrays, hash

I have a set of 100,000 IDs I need to hash into an array that has 50 buckets.

The IDs are of the form: AA00000...AA99999. I know there are functions like md5 available, but those produce digests not indexes into an array. How could I implement a hash such that for each ID it returns an index into my array?

Thanks in advance. (Implementing this in Python)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the built-in [`hash()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash), and use modulus to limit the result to 50:

```
hash(yourid) % 50
```

From the documentation:

> Return the hash value of the object (if it has one). Hash values are integers.

For your given inputs, this picks slots uniformly *enough*:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> histogram = Counter(hash('AA{:05d}'.format(i)) % 50 for i in range(100000))
>>> for i in range(50):
...     print '{:4d}: {}'.format(histogram[i], '*' * (histogram[i] // 40))
... 
1932: ************************************************
1932: ************************************************
1941: ************************************************
1941: ************************************************
1908: ***********************************************
1908: ***********************************************
1974: *************************************************
1974: *************************************************
2012: **************************************************
2012: **************************************************
1898: ***********************************************
1898: ***********************************************
1954: ************************************************
1954: ************************************************
1925: ************************************************
1925: ************************************************
1995: *************************************************
1995: *************************************************
1982: *************************************************
1982: *************************************************
2023: **************************************************
2023: **************************************************
2025: **************************************************
2025: **************************************************
2070: ***************************************************
2070: ***************************************************
2042: ***************************************************
2042: ***************************************************
2028: **************************************************
2028: **************************************************
2120: *****************************************************
2120: *****************************************************
2064: ***************************************************
2064: ***************************************************
2100: ****************************************************
2100: ****************************************************
2057: ***************************************************
2057: ***************************************************
2039: **************************************************
2039: **************************************************
1981: *************************************************
1981: *************************************************
1956: ************************************************
1956: ************************************************
2000: **************************************************
2000: **************************************************
1982: *************************************************
1982: *************************************************
1992: *************************************************
1992: *************************************************
```

Comment: why not `reduce(operator.xor,map(ord,my_string))  % 50` :P (+1)

Comment: Thanks Martijn; does the hash() function generate uniform distribution?

Comment: @JoranBeasley: why have a dog, and then bark yourself, is what I'd like to know..

Comment: I'm running it now and its not giving me a uniform distribution (or even close). What about multiplying each number by 7 or 31 and then summing it together and then using modulus to limit?

Comment: @SamTurani: ah, see, you didn't ask that. I do believe it does though; I added a histogram for you.